# Angular Page is loading before all the data is completed

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I posted on this channel about an issue i was facing few days ago and i am still running into the same problem.

I am currently working on an Angular and Typescript application.

I am making four different api calls, getting data, and rendering it to the UI page.

This function

```
public async getData(){
    let data = await this.http.get<any[]>("google.com").toPromise();
    return data;
}
```

gets the data from the first Api and renders it to the UI which works perfectly fine, if i am only calling the first api. The reason why i need it in sequence is because first call needs to get a particular data before the seconds function kicks in, and it needs that data to start its own process, same with third and fourth function.

This second function

```
 async getValueWithAsync(){
    let data = await this.http.get<any[]>("google.com").toPromise();
    return data;
}
```

is getting the second data from the second Api, and i am calling it from public async getData() like this.

```
const a = await this.getValueWithAsync().then(res => {alert(res)});
```

For some reason, the data is returning, i can see it with alert(res) but the getData() function returns without Data whenever i call getValueWithAsync() while if i don't call it, it comes with data, but the values needed from getData() are undefined which makes sense.

I will appreciate any help once again.

Comment: Why are you converting the Observables into promises?

Comment: Are the functions lacking `return` statements? Maybe it's a typescript thing, but with JavaScript when a function lacks a `return` statement. it returns a value of `undefined`.

Comment: there is a return statement. I edited the statement.

Comment: Because the `.then` method lacks a `return` statement, the constant `a` will resolve as `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
this.getData().then(res => {
    alert(res);
    this.getValueWithAsync().then(res => {
        alert(res)
    });
});
```

Note: if it's not work try with observable